# Как зафиксировать угловую скорость тела?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Есть 2 колеса прикрепленные с помощью WheelJointDef к общему каркасу
Как зафиксировать угловую скорость одного из тел но при этом сохранить амортизацию ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил установкой мотора на скорость 0 и его мощностью регулируется тормозная сила

```
join = world.createJoint(jointDef);
wheelJoint1 = (WheelJoint) join;
wheelJoint1.setMaxMotorTorque(8000);
wheelJoint1.setMotorSpeed(0);
```